# How to fix shutter problem with Magic Lantern on a Canon EOS M?

Tags: canon, magic-lantern

I installed Magic Lantern on my Canon EOS M.  Eventually the shutter is blocked and you can´t take a picture.
The problem is more common with the 22mm F2.0 lens than with the 18-55mm lens.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the Magic Lantern help forums?

Comment: With Magic Lantern--when in doubt--pull the battery out of the camera.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary fixes seem to include partially dismounting and remounting the lens, or power-cycling the camera.

It looks like this is an actual bug in the EOS M build, and they're having a very hard time diagnosing what's going on, although they now suspect it's an issue with the bootloader.  I'd suggest going to [the thread on this bug](https://bitbucket.org/hudson/magic-lantern/issue/1893/eos-m-shutter-bug) and seeing if there's anything you can do to help, testing or debugging-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the shutterbug problem by simply using a better quality SD card, cheap kingston card, shutterbug, better Sandisk card, no shutterbug.

Also i only had the problem with the 18-55mm lens, not the 22mm

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Custom Functions**, and Enable **Release Shutter w/o lens**.